# va_alist ( using variable list in 64 bit machine )

Tags: c, linux, gcc, kernel

I am trying to implement a print function in the kernel module for my learning purposes. I am emulating it on QEMU.

```
#define                va_alist                __builtin_va_alist
#define                va_dcl                  __builtin_va_list_t __builtin_va_list; ...
#define                va_start(ap)         __builtin_varargs_start(ap)
#define                va_arg(ap, type)        __builtin_va_arg((ap), type)
#define                va_end(ap)              __builtin_va_end(ap)
```

But I am getting the error that __builtin_va_alist is undeclared. Should I try to find the definition of __builtin_va_alist also and put it in my include file or am I not aware of something here? Also, If i change __builtin_va_alist to __builtin_va_list ( note: a is not there ), then I am getting an error called `implicit declaration of __builtin_varargs_start` . Kindly help.

Thanks

Chidambaram

Comment: What is your actual question? All of your errors seem obviously expected given your code. What are you expecting? Or what are you not expecting?

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz Actually I dont have the stdarg.h file with me. So I have created a new file named stdarg.h and added these definitions. I expected there will be some function __builtin_va_alist to be present in gcc and that will get executed. Since I got errors like these, I tried to find definitions of __builtin_va_alist. But I was not able to find one. So I wanted to know what was I missing

Comment: Can you show your compile command-line?

Answer (score 4):

How varargs works on x86-64 is actually fairly complicated.

If we take this as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double f=0.7;
    printf("%d %f %p %d %f", 17, f, "hello", 42, 0.8);

    return 0;
}
```

The code it generates is:

```
    .file   "printf.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC1:
    .string "hello"
.LC3:
    .string "%d %f %p %d %f"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $42, %ecx
    movl    $.LC1, %edx
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    movl    $17, %esi
    movsd   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
    movl    $.LC3, %edi
    movl    $2, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   2576980378
    .long   1072273817
    .align 8
.LC2:
    .long   1717986918
    .long   1072064102
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

As you can see, the floating point values are held in `%xmm0` and `%xmm1`, and the `printf` function (like any other varargs function) is "told" how many arguments are passed in SSE registers by the value in `%eax` (2 in this case). Regular arguments are passed in registers, so `%edi`, `%esi`, `%edx`, `%ecx` contain the format string, the first integer argument, the address of `"hello"` and the second integer argument. This follows the standard argument ordering of x86_64.

The compiler normally generates code to then push all the argument registers on the stack, and "fish out" the registers in the `va*` functions.

So if we take the above source code and replace the `printf` with a `myprintf`, which looks like this:

```
void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    int i;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
    case 4:
    {
        double d = va_arg(va, double);
        printf("double %f:", d);
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        long l = va_arg(va, long);
        printf("long %ld:", l);
    }
    }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

at the beginning of `myprintf` it does:

```
    ... 
movq    %rsi, 40(%rsp)
movq    %rdx, 48(%rsp)
movq    %rcx, 56(%rsp)
movq    %r8, 64(%rsp)
movq    %r9, 72(%rsp)
je  .L2
movaps  %xmm0, 80(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm1, 96(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm2, 112(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm3, 128(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm4, 144(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm5, 160(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm6, 176(%rsp)
movaps  %xmm7, 192(%rsp)
.L2:
    ...
```

The code to then fish things out of the stack is quite complicated. This is the floating point side:

```
.L4:
    .cfi_restore_state
    movl    12(%rsp), %edx
    cmpl    $176, %edx
    jae .L5
    movl    %edx, %eax
    addq    24(%rsp), %rax
    addl    $16, %edx
    movl    %edx, 12(%rsp)
.L6:
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    printf
    jmp .L7
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L8:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    leaq    8(%rax), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    jmp .L9
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L5:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    leaq    8(%rax), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    jmp .L6
```

Now, I don't know what compiler flags you are using, because my compiler generates this code with `gcc -O2 -nostdlib -fno-builtin -ffreestanding` without any problem.

Comment: Hi @Mats Peterson. Before anything, thank you so much for taking time to explain me. Now my compiler is running with the following flags `CFLAGS=-O1 -Wall -Werror -nostdinc -Iinclude -msoft-float -mno-sse -fno-builtin -fPIC -mtune=amdfam10 -g3`

Comment: and to add further, I am not able to understand your statement. `the printf function (like any other varargs function) is "told" how many arguments are passed in SSE registers by the value in %eax (2 in this case)`. Since it is 64 bit machine the arguments are passes in register right? Why would the compiler push out arguments into the stack. and really, is there something called `va_alist` as against to `va_list` ?

Comment: Right, I obviously haven't got ALL the files you are using, but if I remove the `-Iinclude` and `-nostdinc` so that it picks up the `stdarg.h` from the "normal" place, the above code compiles fine (with float args I need to remove `-mno-sse` too, but if I remove floating point, it works). Are you using, say, MingW version of gcc, or something?

Comment: It pushes the arguments onto the stack because it's hard to make sure the registers aren't being used, and because it's much easier to store them away all at once than to try to track what registers are used where. It's just a design choice. It would be POSSIBLE to do it in different ways, but the compiler designers choose this way (I was there when the "let's put number of float arguments in `eax` was discussed, but I wasn't there when all the other discussions went on - if there were any discussions).

Comment: I am trying to write a printf code in the kernel module for learning purposes. The Makefile which was given had those compiler flags. And I am using gcc 4.2. So for 64 bit machines we have to use `va_alist` is it? From where I should find the definition of it? I made some brief search over the net , yet not able to find how `__bultin_va_alist` is implemented

Comment: my same code compiles with `va_list` and `va_start` but I dont get correct results. On googling I found they work only for 32 bit machines. And there came this confusion

Comment: Ok, so I'm using gcc 4.6.3 - and that is getting a little old now. I don't have a `va_alist` or ` va_list` in my "stdarg.h", so I'm not sure. But if I just copy the 5 or so #defines in the stdarg into my source file, it works.

Comment: Sorry, I tell a lie, if I don't include `stdio.h`, I'm missing a `va_list`. But either way, it seems like there is a difference between compiler versions, and I'm not really able to help.

Comment: Peterson: Thank you very much. Never mind. I will figure out a way somehow. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Good stuff. I'd just add a reference to the [x86-64 ELF](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86-64-abi-0.99.pdf) ABI.